# Python MySQL TypeError: must be str, not tuple

Tags: python, mysql

I have the following code which connects to a MySQL DB and checks which records are marked as 'active' by a field that has '1' in.

The code then downloads some files using the contents of the `vulntype` field in the URL for the download.

I think the issue lies with the MySQL query or the for loop to do the downloads.

The code is:-

```
import requests
import os
import MySQLdb
from hurry.filesize import size, si
import logging
import logging.handlers
from logging.config import fileConfig

logging.handlers = logging.handlers
fileConfig('data/logging_config.ini')
logger = logging.getLogger("downloader")


active_vuln_type = None


def get_active_vuln_sets():

    global active_vuln_type
    try:
        logging.info('Connecting to the database...')
        active_vuln_type = con = MySQLdb.connect(*******)
        logging.info('Database connected!')
    except FileNotFoundError as fnf:
        logging.error(fnf)
    except MySQLdb.Error as e:
        logging.error(e)
    try:
        logging.info('Getting active vulnerability sets...')
        cur = con.cursor()
        active = "1"
        cur.execute("""SELECT vulntype FROM vuln_sets WHERE active = %s""", (active))
        active_vuln_type = cur.fetchall()
    except MySQLdb.Error as e:
        logging.exception(e)


def download():
    try:
        logging.info('Downloading vulnerability set files...')
        for x in active_vuln_type:
            basepath = os.path.dirname(__file__)
            filepath = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(basepath, ".."))
            response = requests.get('https://vulners.com/api/'
                                    'v3/archive/collection/?type=' + x)
            with open(filepath + '/vuln_files/' + x + '.zip', 'wb') as f:
                f.write(response.content)
            filesize = size(os.path.getsize
                            (filepath + '/vuln_files/'
                             + x + '.zip'), system=si)
            files = x + ".zip - " + str(filesize)
            logging.info('Downloaded ' + x + '.zip Successfully')
            logging.info('File details: ' + files)
    except Exception as e:
        logging.exception(e)
```

The traceback for this is:-

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/luke/projects/vuln_backend/vuln_backend/download.py", line 61, in download
    'v3/archive/collection/?type=' + x)
TypeError: must be str, not tuple
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
active_vuln_type = cur.fetchall()
```

This line returns a list of rows from the database. *Each row is a tuple.* Of course you're only selecting one column from the table, but the interface is the same: each row is a tuple, one value per column.

```
for x in active_vuln_type:
```

Here `x` is a tuple like `("vulnerability of some kind",)`; note the trailing comma. You need to unpack it:

```
for db_row in active_vuln_type:
    x = db_row[0]  # The first and column in the row.
```

Besides that, please consider naming `x` descriptively, returning `active_vuln_type` from one procedure and passing it to the other as a parameter. This will make your code less brittle and easier to test.

```
def get_active_vuln_sets(db_host, db_user, db_password):
   # Do your stuff, using the db credentials....
   return active_vuln_type

def download(active_vuln_type):
   # Same source as now.
```

Now you can `download(get_active_vuln_sets('192.168.100.1', 'joe', 'secret'))`

Or you can test / retry the same thing without touching the DB: `download([("CVE-xyxxy",), ("CVE-asdfghjkl",)])`.

One more thing you can do is to return a clean list of vuln names, not raw DB tuples:

```
def get_active_vuln_sets(...):
    # .....
    return [x[0] for x in cur.fetchall()]
```

Now the value returned will be a list of single, directly usable values, so your original `download(...)` code would work with it.

Comment: That worked! Thank you! How could I re-write it to pass it through as a parameter?

Answer (score 1):

What you get it's a tuple, so you will need to get the first element with x[0]

```
def download():
    try:
        logging.info('Downloading vulnerability set files...')
        for x in active_vuln_type:
            basepath = os.path.dirname(__file__)
            filepath = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(basepath, ".."))
            response = requests.get('https://vulners.com/api/'
                                    'v3/archive/collection/?type=' + x[0])
            with open(filepath + '/vuln_files/' + x[0] + '.zip', 'wb') as f:
                f.write(response.content)
            filesize = size(os.path.getsize
                            (filepath + '/vuln_files/'
                             + x[0] + '.zip'), system=si)
            files = x[0] + ".zip - " + str(filesize)
            logging.info('Downloaded ' + x[0] + '.zip Successfully')
            logging.info('File details: ' + files)
    except Exception as e:
        logging.exception(e)
```

Comment: Factoring out `x[0]` as a separate variable would be tidier.

Answer (score 0):

Reasons to avoid these types of errors: like you have to use try: and except function as I know.

Fetching the data using another source may not be the exect you want.
Is your MySQL DB getting typeerror? Do check which records are marked as 'active' by a field that has '1' in by filtering them.

```
str(function(argument))
```

And it such likes:

```
try:
print(x)
except TypeError:
print("Variable x is not defined")
except:
print("Something else went wrong")
```

And that's all you can pass out your variable by replacing.

I do not think it will work perfectly that you want? But according to [wholeblog](https://wholeblogs.com/typeerror-must-be-str-not-tuple-in-python/)
have to understand the whole code.

If the statement of if and else works then they will pass out some results.

Thank you.